# google maps api jquery infowindow tabs

Tags: jquery, maps, infowindow

Im trying to create tabs in the infowindows in my google maps project.

I am using the $(ex).tabs(); after creating an unordered list inside the html.

Plz help.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should try this
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic10.htm
cheers